# How Can I Install Tensorflow in base (root) environment

Tags: tensorflow, conda

How can I install TensorFlow in the base (root) environment? The only instructions I can find to set up Tensorflow in Anaconda have me create a new environment called `tf` as shown here:

```sh
conda create -n tf tensorflow,
conda activate tf
```

Then when I run my code, I get

```sh
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'.
```

It seems that the Tensorflow module is not being found when it is in the `tf` environment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should activate your base environment first, and then install tensorflow

```sh
conda activate base # activate some environment (here - base)
pip install tensorflow # install tensorflow (can be done via conda too, beware of cpu/gpu versions)
```

This

```sh
conda create -n tf tensorflow
```

creates new environment via `conda create -n tf` and any names after that like `tensorflow` are packages that you want to install in new environment. These packages will be available only in this particular environment. You always install packages in a single environment that is active in the moment.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I will try that. I also just figured out how to switch environments in VS Code, and that solved my problem too. I am just learning Python and Anaconda.